# Is there any way to delimit resources(CPU, RAM usage) to virtual directories on IIS or Apache?

Tags: asp.net, apache, iis, tomcat, resources

We are using ASP.NET but sometimes our applications using very much resources of CPU or RAM. I want to restrict resources for every virtual directory/web site and get alert when they reached the alert level.

I don't know I can do this for IIS but I wonder is this possible for other web servers like apache?

Comment: Are you using Apache Tomcat (Java web application server) or Apache httpd (native web server)?

Comment: Actually I'm coding for IIS with ASP.NET. But in the short term my plan to code for java that's why I asked Apache.

Comment: The term "Apache" is fairly ambiguous and when used on its own usually refers to the Apache Web Server (http://httpd.apache.org/). Apache itself is a software foundation. Apache Tomcat is a Java web application server and completely unrelated to the Apache Web Server.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you cannot have the Java Virtual Machine enforce CPU time limits for certain threads: the best you can do is set the thread priority for any threads that you create. If there is no other work to be done, then a thread will burn as many CPU cycles as it can get unless is it blocking on something (I/O, synchronization monitor, etc.).

Using JMX, you can get some information about threads to possibly detect some runaway-thread situation, but you can't directly control the amount of CPU Time allowed for the thread.

If you are willing to re-architect your dynamic-content and other services, you could write them in such a way that they can support a "unit of work" that is somehow less than the full request's worth of work, and then you can have your request-processing thread execute a unit of work and then sleep an appropriate amount of time. You can lessen your CPU usage by doing this, but you will also certainly slow-down response times measurably.

Is there anything wrong with a fully-utilized CPU if your users are happy? Perhaps the real solution to your problem is more or bigger hardware.